# Where can I get a site data dump?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to do a little poking around with the questions/answers/users of the site to date. Where would I go to get the information for GFH?

Comment: I screen-scraped the questions using Outwit hub. Be good to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

[Stack exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)

I haven't time to look at them myself, unfortunately.

Comment: The data explorer is only for non-beta sites. The api would be a good tool.

Comment: Unfortunately http://data.stackexchange.com/ doesn't seem to work for beta sites... Can't imagine why not?

Comment: I'd love to see a dashboard similar to http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/analysis-of-questions-to-date setup with the APIs that is publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

I've started playing with the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) and believe it can meet your needs. I'm working in python and using [stackpy](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api). Like any api, it's not ideal for a generic data dump since I believe you'd have to iterate thru each instance of each data type. It probably works better if you have a particular function you'd like to perform because then filters and api functions could do alot of the work for you.

Comment: Looking at the SE API, what I'd like to have but can't seem to get is the reputation of the person asking a question _at the time they asked it_. All I can seem to get from the SE API is their current rep... When I get the time I'll check out the stackpy work, it looks promising.